# React-select options are not visible but exist

Tags: css, styled-components, react-select

Im using react-timzone-select and turned out it use react-select.
the problem is the options are exist but not visible until hover.

[image]

Comment: Looks like some CSS conflicts, try to write some CSS and change text color to black.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out that if you are using Argon Dashboard, which is mostly based on Bootstrap 4, inside Bootstrap Modal (notification with background gradient), it overrides React-select׳s menu options.